# pure css pop out sub-menu on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

working on setting up a site, and having a bit of trouble setting up the menu. I would like to set it up so that when someone hovers over one of the buttons on the side menu a sub-menu pops out. Im super new to css and pure for sure, so any help is appreciated.

This is the html thus far.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="side-menu.css" />
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#454545">
<div id="page" align="center">
  <div id="layout"> <a href="#menu" id="menulink" class="menu-link"> </a>
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open"> <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="#">Codetractors</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"> <a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a> </li>
          <li><a href="#"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><strong>Post Job</strong></a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><strong>Browse Jobs</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
          <li><a href="memlogin.html"><strong>Login</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <h2>A subtitle for your page goes here</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2 class="content-subhead">How to use this layout</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="ui.js"></script> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i know that you need to have a  for the sub-menu but from what I have tried everything kept breaking the current menu. Thanks for any help!

here is a jsfiddle. im trying to get the pop out under "post jobs"
http://jsfiddle.net/aaB6u/1/

Comment: What *did* you try? It'd be easier to help if you make a jsfiddle example of your attempt so we can tweak it...

Comment: Not sure the fiddle is working right, I don't see any menu at all. I see the elements, but they're not even showing.

Comment: seems to working fine when i clicked it

Comment: The fiddle gives the following error: `menuLink is null`. Nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaB6u/2/

Comment: Still seeing the same error...

Answer (score 0):

You have way more code in there than you need if all you want to do is create a CSS only hover menu.

Check out this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jG9sF/1/

You'll want to change the layout so the parent menu is absolutely positioned, and then you put a relative position on the children.

```
ul {
    display:none;
}

#manage_menu:hover > ul, li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks that is what I need, but I just cant figure out how to adapt it to mine. Will use it as a reference though.

Comment: What I'd do is comment out your javascript just so you can focus on the css (not sure why you have all that javascript in there). You've got to restructure your html so the menu is a child of the hover element. In your example, your hidden menu isn't 'hidden', it's pushed off the screen by 120px, so you'll need to move your 120px back. Use Chrome dev tools to play with the css until you get it right.